# How do I sort a list of dictionaries by a value of the list?

Tags: python

```
aa = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
bb = [{'b':1, 'c':0, 'd':2, 'a':5}, {'b':5, 'c':6, 'd':1, 'a':2}]
```

I want to arrange the dicts in bb list by aa list.

```
bb = [{'a':5, 'b':1, 'c':0, 'd':2}, {'a':2, 'b':5, 'c':6, 'd':1}]
```

Comment: Why are you trying to sort dicts? Yes, it's possible now that ordering is guaranteed, but why would you want to? It doesn't *mean* anything...

Comment: Dictionaries aren't really meant to be sorted. Why do you want to sort your dictionaries? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Actually, I am developing a process to handle data through api. However, the header of the data is complicated, so I'm trying to sort it

Comment: through api, received data is dictionaries in list.
and i show user that data
but that header of data is very complicate.
so that data refer to received header data list through api...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use list- and dict-comprehensions:

```py
aa = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
bb = [{'b':1, 'c':0, 'd':2, 'a':5}, {'b':5, 'c':6, 'd':1, 'a':2}]

output = [{k: dct[k] for k in aa} for dct in bb]
print(output)
# [{'a': 5, 'b': 1, 'c': 0, 'd': 2}, {'a': 2, 'b': 5, 'c': 6, 'd': 1}]
```

This "sorting" is guaranteed since python 3.7.